# JavaFx : Handle ImageView click inside TableCell

Tags: javafx

I have the following custom table cell implementation

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class TableCellWithImage<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
    private final ImageView image;
    BooleanProperty is_image_visible_ = new SimpleBooleanProperty( false );

    public TableCellWithImage() {
        // add ImageView as graphic to display it in addition
        // to the text in the cell
        image = new ImageView( new Image( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eyes.png")));
        image.setFitWidth(32);
        image.setFitHeight(32);
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);

        setGraphic(image);
        setMinHeight(70);

        setGraphicTextGap(10);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

        setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(true);
        });

        setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(false);
        });

        image.visibleProperty().bind(is_image_visible_);

        setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("cell clicked!");
        });

        image.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Image clicked"); // not called ?
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            // set back to look of empty cell
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(image);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to handle a click event for the ImageView. But I get only cell event handler being called. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it work, wrapping ImageView inside a Button. Here is the final solution :

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class TableCellWithImage<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
    private final ImageView image;
    private final Button image_btn_;
    BooleanProperty is_image_visible_ = new SimpleBooleanProperty( false );

    public TableCellWithImage() {
        // add ImageView as graphic to display it in addition
        // to the text in the cell
        image = new ImageView( new Image( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eyes.png")));
        image.setFitWidth(32);
        image.setFitHeight(32);
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);

        image_btn_ = new Button();
        image_btn_.setGraphic(image);
        image_btn_.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        image_btn_.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("image clicked");
        });

        setMinHeight(70);
        setGraphicTextGap(10);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

        setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(true);
        });

        setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(false);
        });

        image_btn_.visibleProperty().bind(is_image_visible_);

        setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("cell clicked! " + image.isHover());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            // set back to look of empty cell
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(image_btn_);
        }
    }
}
```